# Best way to keep and share huge data between controllers

Tags: angularjs

The App I'm building is complex and the data is huge. It is an order administration dispatch app.

At the beginning the first thing I have to do it to get from the API all the orders, all the stores and all the couriers.

During the life cycle of an order I receive several updates from the API and I handle everything through Server Sent Events.

Once I load the data I put everything in 3 different `$scope`: `$scope.orders`, `$scope.stores` and `$scope.couriers` and a I created a service to handle and share updated data between controllers.

One of the service look like this:

```
App.factory('Orders', ['logs', function (logs) {

    var orders = {};
    var newOrder = null;
    var updatedOrder = null;

    orders.list = [];

    orders.getNewOrder = function () {
        return newOrder;
    };

    orders.setNewOrder = function (order) {
        newOrder = order;
    };

    orders.updateOneOrder = function (index, order) {
        orders.list[index] = order;
        updatedOrder = order;
    };

    orders.getUpdatedOrder = function () {
        return updatedOrder;
    };

    orders.getAllOrders = function () {
        return orders.list;
    };

    return orders;

}]);
```

And I `$watch` for those methods to see changes and update the relative `$scope`.

As you can see in my service I have one more Array to store data in order to be able to handle it due to the fact I can not use `$scope` in a Factory.

I followed a guide online regarding this. I know there is also Broadcast and Emit but probably it was too complex to handle all those things with that method.

One more thing I avoided is to store orders, stores and couriers in `$rootScope`.

I think the App is a bit slow and use a lot of memory to handle everything so I wish to know the best practice to handle huge data that need to be shared between controllers and updated in real time...

I think my method at the moment is using too much memory.

Comment: `At the beginning the first thing I have to do it to get from the API all the orders, all the stores and all the couriers` - this sort of defeats the point of an Angular app. You should probably retrieve only the *relevant portion* of the data and only *when* it is needed.

Comment: I need everything at the beginning... I have a list of orders to show, the list of stores and a google maps with all couriers position.

Comment: Surely the user is not actually seeing *all* orders, stores and couriers right when the application loads. If that's the case, then the data is probably not huge. From your description, I would guess that the first n (e.g. 10) of each would suffice. The rest can be loaded as needed, for example when the user begins to scroll.

Comment: Maybe LocalStorage/ HTML5 Web Storage could be an option and then you could only load the data currently needed to your scope (if you are not allowed to change the backend services to load only the things you are actually need at a specific moment).